# $p(x)$ irreducible implies $(p(x))$ radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, radicals, irreducible-polynomials

Reviewing a bit of algebra, the following concern arose me:

*Let $p(x)$ be a irreducible polynomial in $K[x_1,x_2,..., x_n]$. Is $(p(x))$ radical?*

I think the answer is yes, however I have not been able to find a proof.

I know that to prove this I just must to verify that, if $p|qh$, then $p|q$ or $p|h$ by irreducibility. But this is not clear for me...

Comment: What do you know about UFDs?

Comment: Ohhh because my $K$ is a field, $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a UFD and therefore, mean argument of @joshua follows my concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $(p(x))$ is prime. Prime ideals are radical. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of a ring $R$. Then $x^n\in P$ implies $x\in P$ as $P$ is prime, so $P$ is radical.

Comment: Why $p$ irreducible implies $(p)$ prime?... I know that this is true for PIDs, but $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is not necessary like such

Comment: My apologies. I forget that this result is true for UFDs too...thanks a lot!